# Create general symbolic array using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I want to generate array or `1 x M` matrix with variables such as (please note that sum goes from `i=1` to `m-1`): 
[image]

Because I want to use `Obj` later as a general array depends on given `M` for some optimization purposes. I tried following code in MATLAB but that symbolic `L` does not support:

```
function testSymbolic
M=3;
Obj = ones(1,M);
L = sym('L', [1 M]);

tempL = log(1-L);
for m=1:M
    Obj(1,m) =  log((L(m))/(1+L(m))) + sum(tempL(1,1:m-1),2);
end
Obj
```

However, when I see that following when I run separately:

```
L = sym('L', [1 3])
L =
[ L1, L2, L3]

L(1)
ans =
L1
```

can some one please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When I run your code (without the line `Obj = ones(1,M);`), I get e.g. `Obj(3) = log(L3/(L3 + 1)) + log(1 - L1) + log(1 - L2)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I want to get `L(1), L(2), L(3),...` etc instead of `L1, L2, ...` I can write each `Obj(1,m)` separately if `M` is smaller, but it can be more than `10`. So I am looking for general setup.

Comment: For example, when `M=3`, I should have output as `Obj = [log(L(1)/(L(1)+1)),  log(L(2)/(L(2)+1))+log(1-L(1)),  log(L(3)/(L(3)+1))+log(1-L(1))+log(1-L(2))]`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
M = 3;
for i = 1:M
    L(i) = sym(['L(' num2str(i) ')'])
end

tempL = log(1-L);
for m=1:M 
Obj(1,m) =  log((L(m))/(1+L(m))) + sum(tempL(1:m-1));
end
```

This yields e.g.

```
Obj(3)

ans =

log(L(3)/(L(3) + 1)) + log(1 - L(1)) + log(1 - L(2))
```

EDIT: 
Considering you want to calculate the maximum of the `Obj`-vector I would suggest this:

```
clear;
M = 3;

L = sym('L', [1 M]);

tempL = log(1-L);
for m=1:M 
    Obj(1,m) =  real(log((L(m))/(1+L(m))) + sum(tempL(1:m-1)));
end

F = matlabFunction(Obj,'vars',{L})
ft = @(v) (max (-F(v)));
```

Now you can optimize `ft`.

Comment: Thanks @jolo. I want to use `Obj` in such function `F=@(L) max(-[Obj])`. Since `L` is in `str` format, I cannot use for symbolic manipulation after that. Do you have any solution for that? Please share with me :)

Comment: `L` is not an array of strings but an array of symbolic objects named `L(1), ... , L(M)`, which might be confusing, as `L(i)` also refers to the i's element of the array `L`. Please clarify for me.

Comment: Why I cannot pass `Obj` into `F=@(L) max(-[Obj])`, and do optimization using `[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0],[1;1;1])`. But when Manually enter `Obj`, it works. For example `F=@(L) max(-[log(L(1)/(L(1)+1)) log(L(2)/(L(2)+1))+log(1-L(1)) log(L(3)/(L(3)+1))+log(1-L(1))+log(1-L(2))]);
[L,fval]=fmincon(F,[0.5 0.5 0.5],[],[],[],[],[0;0;0],[1;1;1])`

Comment: Matlab doesn't support a symbolic `max` function, as far as I know. I updated my answer how to get a function that can be used as you want to, if I understand your comment correctly.